# How to receive detailed reputation from SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Using the API it is possible to receive the detailed user reputation like this:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#ids=1719510&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true
```

How is it possible to make it on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an [initial query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1160851?UserId=1719510) that gives you the most common reputation events from the Votes Table:

```
;with postvotes as
(
select v.creationdate
     , p.id postid 
     , case v.votetypeid
       when  1 then 'accepts'
       when 2 then 'up-votes'
       when 3 then 'down-votes'
       when 9 then 'bounty_recieved'
       end  vote_type
     , case p.posttypeid 
       when 1 then 'question'
       when 2 then 'answer'
       end post_type
     , sum(case  v.votetypeid 
           when 1 then 15
           when 2 then 10
           when 3 then -2
           when 9 then bountyamount
           end
       ) reputation_change

from votes v
inner join posts p on p.id = v.postid
where p.owneruserid = ##userid?1719510##
and posttypeid in (1,2)
and votetypeid in (1,2,3,9)
group by v.creationdate, p.id, votetypeid, posttypeid
),
bounties as 
(
select v.creationdate
     , v.postid postid 
     , 'bounty-offered' vote_type
     , 'question' post_type
     , sum(bountyamount) reputation_change
from votes v
where v.userid = ##userid?1719510##
and votetypeid = 8
group by v.creationdate, v.postid, votetypeid
),
approvededits as
(
select se.creationdate
     , se.postid postid 
     , 'approved-edit' vote_type
     , case p.posttypeid 
       when 1 then 'question'
       when 2 then 'answer'
       end  post_type
     , sum(2) reputation_change
from suggestededits se
inner join posts p on p.id = se.postid
where se.Owneruserid = ##userid?1719510##
and approvaldate is not null
group by se.creationdate, se.postid, posttypeid
)


select *
from postvotes
union
select *
from bounties
union 
select *
from approvededits
```

The daily reputation caps are not factored in.

When run today this will be your result:

[image]

Have a look at the Data Explorer schema post [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) to learn more about its tables and fields.

Most voting events are stored in the Votes table, a row per votetype, indicated by the VotetypeId. In the VoteTypes tables you find what each votetypeid means. Some  example votetypeids are 1 = accept, 2 = up vote, 3 = down vote, 5 = favorite, 8 = bounty start, 9 = bounty award.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.
Give a big shout out to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for her awesome [SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).
Say "Hi!" in [SEDE Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) if you have any inquiries.

Comment: Thank you. Any small hind please on how I could check how to receive all reputation-history actions like accepted answer, boundies etc.?

Comment: @Nathalie I added some explanation what and how the votes are stored.

Comment: thank you. I guess know I can add other options of reputation history such as accepted answer +2 etc?

Comment: @Nathalie +2 for an accepted answer should be obtained from the Posts table by looking if the acceptedanswerid is not null.