# Receive the full reputation from SEDE query

Tags: support, data-explorer

Using [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391786/11786778) query it is possible to receive many different options of reputation history.

```
;with postvotes as
(
select v.creationdate
     , p.id postid 
     , case v.votetypeid
       when  1 then 'accepts'
       when 2 then 'up-votes'
       when 3 then 'down-votes'
       when 9 then 'bounty_recieved'
       end  vote_type
     , case p.posttypeid 
       when 1 then 'question'
       when 2 then 'answer'
       end post_type
     , sum(case  v.votetypeid 
           when 1 then 15
           when 2 then 10
           when 3 then -2
           when 9 then bountyamount
           end
       ) reputation_change

from votes v
inner join posts p on p.id = v.postid
where p.owneruserid = ##userid?1719510##
and posttypeid in (1,2)
and votetypeid in (1,2,3,9)
group by v.creationdate, p.id, votetypeid, posttypeid
),
bounties as 
(
select v.creationdate
     , v.postid postid 
     , 'bounty-offered' vote_type
     , 'question' post_type
     , sum(bountyamount) reputation_change
from votes v
where v.userid = ##userid?1719510##
and votetypeid = 8
group by v.creationdate, v.postid, votetypeid
),
approvededits as
(
select se.creationdate
     , se.postid postid 
     , 'approved-edit' vote_type
     , case p.posttypeid 
       when 1 then 'question'
       when 2 then 'answer'
       end  post_type
     , sum(2) reputation_change
from suggestededits se
inner join posts p on p.id = se.postid
where se.Owneruserid = ##userid?1719510##
and approvaldate is not null
group by se.creationdate, se.postid, posttypeid
)


select *
from postvotes
union
select *
from bounties
union 
select *
from approvededits
```

I tried the query for a random selection.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1160851/how-to-receive-detailed-reputation-from-sede?UserId=1719510

And these are the results. However if I cross check which the reputation history:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=53
I can see that it has not the start days such as   "Oct 21 '14". Any suggestions what updates it could be made in the query to receive all options of reputation?

Answer (score 3):

The answer those votes came in on has been deleted.

You can't track reputation gained on deleted posts using SEDE. This rarely is a problem, since deleting a post often resets reputation, but exceptions apply and this is one of those exceptions.

There's no workaround for this (afaik).